# replace variable names with the values of the respective variables

Tags: php, regex, function

I'm trying to replace variable name with its value here's sample:

```
<?php
$string = "value";
$$string = "value2";
?>
```

So practically $$string must be $value right ? Whan i'm trying to do is to make $$string to $value, i've tried to do some things with regex but it's not working here's my code:

```
<?php

function var_replaced($code)
{
}
$code = htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents("file.php"));
$code = preg_replace_callback("/$$ (.+?) /i",'var_replaced', $code);
echo $code;
?>
```

The point is after i use this function var_replaced my code will become:

```
<?php
$value = "value2";
?>
```

Any idea how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to consider two things. The callback will execute with another local variable context. It won't have the outside `$string` in reach. Therefore it's one of the cases where you need the `preg_replace` with `/e`val switch.

Also your regex is way off. You have some spaces in there, and the `.+?` won't know where to stop. It would just look at one character.

You must constrain the placeholder here. Best to look for alphanumeric characters.

Thirdly you must escape `$` as that represents line or subject end.

So the approach for what you're describing would be:

```
$code = preg_replace("/[$][$](\w+)/e", '$$$1', $code);
```

However, use the `_callback` if you can, by hoarding your replacement variables in an array. Then do an array lookup in your callback:

```
function var_replaced($match)
{
    list(, $varname) = $match;
    $reference = $GLOBALS["yourvars"][$varname];
    $value = $GLOBALS["yourvars"][$reference];
    return $value;
}
```

This manually looks up the first key to be interpreted as another variable name, then fetches the value for the rewritten variable name.

I'm entirely clueless if that's what you were asking for though.

Comment: the regex you wrote is not working the way i want it prints: value2
i want to make $$string to be $value.... by using the value of $string...

Comment: If you actually want some source code transformation and interpretation, a regex won't do. The regex itself works for looking up variable names. What you need to expand on is the complexity of the replacement callback. And to remotely accomplish what you want, you'd first have to collect variable names and values, and then run a second time to replace parts. This is unattainable except for the simplest of syntax cases (two variable declarations right after each other). So, no.